# Python многократное использование input

Tags: python-3.x, input

Как можно реализовать выход обратно в `input` (который отвечает за действия)? Программа заканчивается после одного использования `input`, но можно ли его использовать много раз?

```
import random
money = 300
frase1 = "Ну что, наворовал?"

name = input("Привет! Какое твоё имя? -> ")

print("Хорошо, " + name + ". Привет! Ну а теперь пора выживать...\n")

print("Твои деньги: " + str(money) + "\n")

print("1.Купить палатку(250руб.)\n2.Купить кроссы(300руб)")

print("\n3.Лазить по помойкам(+10-100руб.)\n4.Поборы(50-150руб.)\n5.Мелкое воровство(200-1000руб.)")

choose = input("Твой выбор -> ")

if choose == "1" and money >= 250:
    print(name + " ты купил палатку за 250руб!")
    print("Твои деньги: " + str(money - 250))

if choose == "2" and money >= 300:
    print(name + " ты купил кроссы за 300руб!")
    print("Твои деньги: " + str(money - 300))

if choose == "3":
    final = random.randint(10,100)
    print("+" + str(final) + "руб.")
    print(frase2)
    after = money + final
    print("Твои деньги: " + str(after))

if choose == "4":
    finall = random.randint(50,150)
    print("+" + str(finall) + "руб.")
    afterr = money + finall
    print("Твои деньги: " + str(afterr))

if choose == "5":
    finall = random.randint(200,1000)
    print("+" + str(finall) + "руб.")
    print(frase1)
    afterr = money + finall
    print("Твои деньги: " + str(afterr))
```

Comment: оффтоп: похоже на игру)

Comment: Да, игрушку тестовую делаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте бесконечный цикл:

```
while True:
    # ...
    print("\n q - Выход")
    # ...
    if choose == "q":
        exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_money():
    global money
    choose = input("Твой выбор -> ")

    if choose == "1" and money >= 250:
        print(10)
        money -= 10
    elif choose == "2" and money >= 300:
        print(20)
        money -= 20

    return not choose == "q"   

money = 300
while check_money():
    money += 1
    print('money %s' % money)
```